# Puzzle: Cumulative Sum Divisible by 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If we sum the first $4$ positive integers, we get $4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 10$, which I think is pretty cool.

I'm interested in seeing solutions to the following puzzle:  If we take the cumulative sum of the first $N$ positive integers, how many times along the way will the sum be divisible by $10$?

In other words, define:
$$f(N) = \left|\left\{n \leq N \;:\; \sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \text{ is divisible by $10$}\right\} \right|$$

Is there a nice expression for $f(N)$?

Comment: I think this is a great question!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need $20$ to divide $n(n+1)$. Note $n$ and $n+1$ are of opposite parity. Hence, $4$ divides either $n$ or $n+1$. $5$ divides either $n$ or $n+1$ since $5$ is a prime.
Hence, we have $4$ cases which gives us as discussed below.

$1$. $4|n$ and $5|n$. This case is trivial. Since $(4,5)=1$, we get that $20|n$ and hence $n \equiv 0\bmod 20$.

$2$. $4|n$ and $5|(n+1)$. This means that $n = 4k_4$ and $n+1 = 5k_5$. Hence, we get that $5k_5 - 4k_4 = 1$.

Solving such general congruence fall under the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), as TMM points out in the comments, and is certainly something which you should look at. In this case, we solve it as follows. Clearly, $(k_4,k_5) = (1,1)$ is a solution. In general, if $ax+by$ has integer solutions and $(x_0,y_0)$ is one such integer solution, then *all* integer solutions are given by $$(x,y) = \displaystyle \left( x_0 + k \frac{\text{lcm}[\lvert a \rvert,\lvert b \rvert]}{a}, y_0 - k \frac{\text{lcm}[\lvert a \rvert,\lvert b \rvert]}{b} \right)$$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Hence, we get that $(k_4,k_5) = (1+5k,1+4k)$. This gives us that $n = 20k+4$ i.e. $n \equiv 4 \bmod 20$.

$3$. $4|(n+1)$ and $5|n$. This means that $n = 5k_5$ and $n+1 = 4k_4$. Hence, we get that $4k_4 - 5k_4 = 1$. Clearly, $(k_4,k_5) = (4,3)$ is a solution. Hence, we get that $(k_4,k_5) = (4+5k,3+4k)$. This gives us that $n=20k+15$ i.e. $n \equiv 15 \bmod 20$.

$4$. $4|(n+1)$ and $5|(n+1)$. This case is again trivial. Since $(4,5) = 1$, we get that $20|(n+1)$ and hence $n \equiv 19 \bmod 20$.

To summarize, the solutions are given by

\begin{cases}
n \equiv 0\bmod 20 &(\text{ if }4 \text{ divides }n \text{ and }5 \text{ divides }n)\\
n \equiv 4\bmod 20 & (\text{ if }4 \text{ divides }n \text{ and }5 \text{ divides }n+1)\\
n \equiv 15\bmod 20 & (\text{ if }4 \text{ divides }n+1 \text{ and }5 \text{ divides }n)\\
n \equiv 19\bmod 20 & (\text{ if }4 \text{ divides }n+1 \text{ and }5 \text{ divides }n+1)
\end{cases}

Comment: (+1) although I think mentioning the Chinese Remainder Theorem would have been nice

Answer (score 8):

Write $n$ in the form $20k+j$ where $0≤j<20$.

Then you have $n(n+1) = (20k+j)(20k+j+1) = 400k^2 + 40kj + 20k + j^2 + j$ which is obviously a multiple of 20 if and only if $j^2+j$ is.  So the problem has been reduced to finding $0≤j<20$ where $j(j+1)$ is a multiple of 20; this occurs for $j=0,4,15,19$, so the solutions all have the form $n=20k+\{0,4,15,19\}$ for some integer $k$.

---

Where did I get the inspiration to write $n$ in the form $20k+j$?  I guessed that it would repeat with period 10 or 20, and I looked at [the list of triangular numbers in OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000217) and saw that multiples of 10 did indeed appear at $n=4,15,19,20,24$, so 20 seemed to be the way to go.

Why did I guess that it would repeat with period 10 or 20? The main reason is that questions about when an polynomial $P(n)$ is divisible by $q$ usually does something like that, because if you calculate $P(n+q) - P(n)$ the constant term cancels, as do all the terms that are pure in $n$, and leaves you with some higher-order terms that are all divisible by $q$.

I knew that was the thing to try because I have seen a lot of problems of that type.

Addendum: How many solutions lie between 1 and $N$?  Write $N=20k+j$ as before, and the answer is $4k$ plus a fudge factor.  The fudge factor is 0 if $j<4$, 1 if $4≤j<15$, 2 if $15≤j<19$, and 3 if $j=19$.

Comment: I can't see why your substitution is useful, given that the conclusion is the same as the premise: n(n + 1) must be a multiple of 20, j(j + 1) must be a multiple of 20. Am I missing something?

Comment: @uncleZeiv: The difference is that while $n$ can be any number, $j$ must be less than 20.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $ $ If $\rm\:m,n,i\in \mathbb Z\:$ and $\rm\:(n,i) = 1\:$ with $\rm\:m,\:\!m\!+\!i\:$ powers of distinct primes, then

$\rm\quad\phantom{m\!|\:\!\rm n\!+\!i,}\:\ m(m\!+\!i)\:|\:n(n\!+\!i)\ $ iff one of the four following cases holds

$\quad\begin{eqnarray}
\rm &&&\rm m(m\!+\!i)\!\!\! &|&\rm n &\ \iff\ &\rm n\equiv\:\ \ 0&\rm\pmod{\:m(m\!+\!i)} \\
\rm &&&\rm m(m\!+\!i)\!\!\!&|&\rm n\!+\!i &\ \iff\ &\rm n\equiv -i&\rm\pmod{\:m(m\!+\!i)} \\
\rm m\!&|\:&\rm n,\!\!\!\!&\rm \phantom{m(}m\!+\!i\:&|&\rm n\!+\!i &\ \iff\ &\rm n\equiv\ m&\rm\pmod{\:m(m\!+\!i)} \\ 
\rm m\!&|&\:\!\rm n\!+\!i,\!\!\!\! &\rm \phantom{m(}m\!+\!i\!\!\!\!\!\!\:&|&\rm n &\ \iff\ &\rm n\equiv -m\!-\!i\!\!\!\!\:&\rm\pmod{\:m(m\!+\!i)} 
\end{eqnarray}$

Put $\rm\ m=4,\ i=1\:$ to solve your problem.

Hint for the proof: for prime powers $\rm\:p^k\:|\:n(n\!+\!i)\!\iff\! p^k\:|\:n\:$ or $\rm\:p^k\:|\:n\!+\!i\:$ by $\rm\:n,n\!+\!i\:$ coprime, by $\rm (n,n\!+\!i)=(n,i) = 1.$

Answer (score 2):

Only the ones digit matters when figuring multiples of ten.  Also, a multiple of ten plus a multiple of ten is a multiple of ten.  Thus, we can find the applicable patterns that we need to consider:

First pattern to get to a multiple of ten (starting with 1):

```
1+2+3+4 = 10
```

Second pattern (starting from 5, since we counted 4 last in the previous pattern):

```
5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5 = 50
```

Third pattern (starting from 6):

```
6+7+8+9 = 30
```

Fourth pattern (starting from 5):

```
0
```

Repeat back to pattern 1

---

Now we have the 4 sequential patterns that we need to consider, which consist of 20 total numbers.  I'm more of a programmer than a mathematician, so here's one way to represent the solution programmatically (in this case using JavaScript), with a [working fiddle to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/5976v/):

```
function getMultiplesOfTenWhileCountingTo(finalCount){
    //There are 4 multiples every 20 numbers
    var multiples = Math.floor(finalCount/20) * 4;

    //Add the additional multiples based on the remainder
    var remainder = finalCount % 20;
    if(remainder >= 4){
        multiples++;
    } 
    if(remainder >= 15){
        multiples++;
    }
    if(remainder >= 19){
        multiples++;
    }
    return multiples;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the expression

$$f(N)=\#\left\{n\le N:\sum_{i=1}^n i=n(n+1)2 \text{ is divisible by 10}\right\},$$

each time when the $n=4,64,1024$, etc., take the root (e.g. in $2^2$, $2^6$, $2^{10}$),     therefore, you can form your function in following two ways:

1. $\text{power}\,\%\,4=2$;
2. An arithmetic progression with first term 2 and $d=4$, will give you the powers of two.

Apologies for bad formatting.